# MS ACCESS Convert to UNICODE

Tags: sql, ms-access, unicode, utf-8

I have MS ACCESS DB with non unicode columns 
i need to import it on SQL Server 
How i can convert it to unicode to import?

Comment: nobody now solotuions?

Comment: What does "non unicode" mean? You're columns just have regular ASCII characters? Nothing fancy? What is the problem here?

Comment: Columns ara ASCII , i need to import it to sql , in sql i need UNICODE

Comment: Can you add some examples of what your data look like? If they are just a font over top all the low numbered characters (<128 bits) then you will likely need a translation table because Sql Server (or whatever engine you're putting the data into) doesn't know fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
StringUnicode = StrConv(Ascii, vbUnicode)
```

In a query:

```
StringUnicode: StrConv([AsciiField], 64)
```

But I doubt your data are not Unicode because Access defaults to Unicode.

Comment: they are Armenian fonts and Russian cyrillic  not unicode

Comment: OK. Then you'll need a translation table to convert the current ansi/ascii values to the corresponding Unicode values that hold your Armenian (Cyrillic) character set. You may be able to browse for this.